# Scanner seen by sane-find-scanner but not scanimage

Tags: release-juno

root@DXP051:/etc/sane.d/dll.d# sane-find-scanner

# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

??????????????????????????? (my wifi dongle) ?????????????????????
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x012d [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:002
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

# Not checking for parallel port scanners.

# Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

---

root@DXP051:/etc/sane.d/dll.d# scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
root@DXP051:/etc/sane.d/dll.d#

---

There is a deb file from Epson for this scanner, but oddly it shows as a directory rather than a file, so I don't understand how to install it. Running install.sh is successful, but doesn't change anything.

[image]